# CPU baking only uses a fraction of the CPU, starting with 2.90

Tags: python, baking

I just updated the blender version from 2.83 to 2.91 for our baking scripts, and it was running smooth in my local machine tests (GPU rendering), but when we ran the first test jobs on AWS machines (with CPU rendering), it was really slow. From 25mn to bake a few lightmaps, it went to more than 4 hours. The only thing that we changed in the code were two breaking changes from 2.91:

```
scene.ray_cast(layer, ray_origin, world_normal)
# became
scene.ray_cast(layer.depsgraph, ray_origin, world_normal)

#and 

bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(export_materials=True)
#became
bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(export_materials='EXPORT')
```

In the logs, from what I can see, there's not much difference. The most suspicious difference is that in the bakes with 2.83 there was this line before each bake:

```
Fra:0 Mem:593.81M (0.00M, Peak 725.36M) | Time:00:15.92 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene | Loading render kernels (may take a few minutes the first time)
```

Which is now absent from bakes done in 2.91. Because the logs are reaaally long (90k+ lines) it's difficult to do a thorough analysis. All I can see, when searching for the lines I log before and after baking one map, is that the logged time is much slower with 2.91 and that the line stated above is absent at the beginning. There's not much more I can see...

EDIT: Comparing the documentation for [BakeSettings](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BakeSettings.html) from 2.91 to 2.83 I see there is now a "max_ray_distance" parameter, that is set to infinity by default. It might be my problem. Gonna try and tweak it.

EDIT2: the max_ray_distance parameter didn't change a thing. I was able to reproduce the issue on my computer, and observed that while baking with 2.83 uses 100% of the CPU, on 2.92 it uses almost nothing.
Gonna try the 2.92 beta next and 2.90 to see how they behave

EDIT3: I tried making a simple blender project to reproduce the problem and open an issue. But strangely, the problem did not occur then. There must be something we're doing in our code that makes it behave differently than just making a simple plane mesh and hitting the bake button...

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason! We were setting the tile size to the size of the map. According to the comment next to the code it was an optimisation recommended on Blender forums, and indeed it was way faster than setting a small tile size on 2.83. On 2.90 however, it was sluggish as hell. Setting a 32 tile size made things much better (it's even a wee bit faster than with 2.83)

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that now your CPU is having to complete more tasks as it is a new version and it may have different processes to complete?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It seems to be performing the same tasks as before, just slower.
What is weird is that rendering is not affected (it still uses 100% of the CPU), only baking. From what I understand, baking is performing several small renders, so I would imagine some of the code would be the same for both? That's what it looks like anyway from the logs.